# Testing equality of betas of multiple assets in the Capital Asset Pricing Model

Tags: finance

I am trying to understand how I can test whether the factor loadings (Beta) in CAPM for different stocks are statistically different between each other. I.e. I have 3 stocks with different CAPM betas. How can I test that those 3 betas are statistically different between each other?

Do you have an approach to do so and how do you justify that? I have been unable to find much in the literature.

Comment: Cross posted from [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608140).